# Timings with Spring application contexts

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently trying to track down a performance issue and I've found a large amount of time is being spent in the code where you request a bean from a ApplicationContext:

```
ApplicationContext.getBean(String beanName);
```

Do you know if it's possible to turn on any debug or log information within Spring so that I can see all the objects that are instantiated from this call as well as the times to create them?

I've been trying to profile with Yourkit, but the operation only take 1.4 seconds in total and only on the first call, so Yourkit seems to struggle with short lived, one off calls like this.

It's why I was heading down the logging route.

Answer (score 3):

Spring uses log4j, so you can set your log level to debug and see what you get.  It'll be a lot of output.  I'd advice not logging it to the console - write it to a file.

How did draw that conclusion?  Are you profiling your app with Visual VM, with all the plugins installed?

I'd bet that the app context is not the issue.  If the time spent in the app context is large, it should just be on startup when Spring is reading and parsing the configuration, instantiating and wiring beans.  Once it's done the cost is amortized over the life of your app.  For most web apps this is a startup cost, not a reflection on the experience users have when using your site.

It's far more likely to be in your code.  Be sure that you aren't being mislead by not taking a comprehensive view.

Comment: +1. Profiling helps - could be anything from non-singleton beans waiting on resources in constructor/@PostConstruct to misleading debug output...

Comment: So?  You should still profile and act on more data.  I don't believe that Spring is the issue.  It's something else.

Comment: Prototype-scoped beans that take a long time to construct by Spring could be the culprit. Do some logging to see what the app context is up to.

Comment: Any class that performs expensive initialization, regardless of whether it is constructed by Spring or your own code. These can add up if prototype beans (new instances that is) are constructed continuously.

Comment: All theoretical.  I'd like to know what beans would take a long time.  Those needing connections of some kind might, but they ought to be fed by pools.  Pools might take time, but that's just on startup.  I don't recall database connection pools with 50 connections being oppressive.  Still sounds theoretical to me.

Comment: Heh, well given the huge amount of context and detail in the OP's question, there's not much to do but theoretize. =) Anyways, crappy code, stuff that calls/spawns external resources, locking, scanning etc. are all POSSIBLE causes for slowing down bean initialization. NB: "Pools might take time, but that's just on startup." => for PROTOTYPE-scoped beans that startup cost would be incurred on every call to getBean(..).